# LoadRunner, backend error running a script with more than 1 Vuser

Tags: concurrency, scripting, correlation, loadrunner

I'm having trouble with a LR script running with multiple concurrent users.  The script creates a medication and then deletes it.  The script passes and LR thinks it actually deletes the med, but it doesn't and we get a error in our systems error log.   I can run, for example, a 20 min/1 Vuser test with this script and it works fine, meds are deleted, no errors in our log.  Also, when replaying the script from the LR Controller, it works fine as well.

When running with 2+ users, is when I see problems.  My DBA says the error in our logs is thrown because the stored procedure logic on the MedDC.asp page attempts to update a patient list and the PatientUserCode is not getting passed through.  He has no clue why this is happening or how to resolve it.

I've tried manually correlation the parameter values many different ways and none have been successful.  Is there anything I can do in my script to get around this? Here is my section of script code for deleting the med including the correlation parameter code.  Any help is appreciated.

Correlation parameter logic

```
web_reg_save_param_regexp(
    "ParamName=MedDC.asp?DelMedID",
    "RegExp=cb\\ value=\"(.*?)\\|MedOnly",
    SEARCH_FILTERS,
    "Scope=Body",
    "IgnoreRedirections=No",
    LAST);

web_convert_param("MedDC.asp?DelMedID_URL2",
    "SourceString=MedDC.asp?DelMedID",
    "SourceEncoding=HTML",
    "TargetEncoding=URL",
    LAST);
```

Delete med script logic

```
lr_think_time(40);

web_url("MedDC.asp",
    "URL=https://tempv2.docsynergy.com/DocSynergy/CentralMR/MedDC.asp?PatientUserCode=360690&ID={MedDC.asp?DelMedID}&OrderID=&EditType=DCMed",
    "Resource=0",
    "RecContentType=text/html",
    "Referer=https://tempv2.docsynergy.com/DocSynergy/CentralMR/PatientInfo.asp?PatientUserCode=360690",
    "Snapshot=t125.inf",
    "Mode=HTTP",
    LAST);

web_concurrent_start(NULL);

web_url("iframeCal.htm_2",
    "URL=https://tempv2.docsynergy.com/scriptfiles/jscriptlib/iframeCal.htm",
    "Resource=0",
    "RecContentType=text/html",
    "Referer=https://tempv2.docsynergy.com/DocSynergy/CentralMR/MedDC.asp?PatientUserCode=360690&ID={MedDC.asp?DelMedID_URL2}&OrderID=&EditType=DCMed",
    "Snapshot=t126.inf",
    "Mode=HTTP",
    LAST);

web_url("Blank.htm_22",
    "URL=https://tempv2.docsynergy.com/DocSynergy/CentralMR/Blank.htm",
    "Resource=0",
    "RecContentType=text/html",
    "Referer=https://tempv2.docsynergy.com/DocSynergy/CentralMR/MedDC.asp?PatientUserCode=360690&ID={MedDC.asp?DelMedID_URL2}&OrderID=&EditType=DCMed",
    "Snapshot=t127.inf",
    "Mode=HTTP",
    LAST);

web_concurrent_end(NULL);

/* Discontinue box is displayed. */

/* Clicked delete, click OK on delete pop-up. */

web_add_cookie("IdleStartTime=Wed%20Aug%209%2015%3A17%3A43%20CDT%202017; DOMAIN=tempv2.docsynergy.com");

lr_think_time(51);

web_url("MedDC.asp_2",
    "URL=https://tempv2.docsynergy.com/DocSynergy/CentralMR/MedDC.asp?DelMedID={MedDC.asp?DelMedID}",
    "Resource=0",
    "RecContentType=text/html",
    "Referer=https://tempv2.docsynergy.com/DocSynergy/CentralMR/MedDC.asp?PatientUserCode=360690&ID={MedDC.asp?DelMedID_URL2}&OrderID=&EditType=DCMed",
    "Snapshot=t128.inf",
    "Mode=HTTP",
    LAST);
```

Answer (score 0):

Would two doctors every use the same patient ID?  It's possible that you have a delete failure because the record/page is locked against these actions in the DB as you have an update from your second user on the same patient ID.

Comment: Good point, it's not uncommon tho, but would be uncommon happening at the same time I suppose.  What about having the script randomly select a PatientUserCode from a set range.  That might be a resolution, but I am not sure how to do that.  Any advice on how I could do that?

Comment: See parameterization

Comment: Thanks, so I got the parameterization to work for PatientUserCode and setup a parameter file with 10 patients and ran a 5 user load test and verified meds were getting submitted across multiple patients.  However, we still got flooded with the error in our logs, so it's very confusing that it only happens when running via the load generator with multiple users.  Our dev also made an additional code change to that page to ensure no PatientUserCode could get passed as a Null value.

Comment: Do you have think time enabled in your script execution?  Do you have integrated monitoring to understand what resource is being impinged when this occurs?  Are you pulling the HTTP logs at the end and checking for insight?